# WTForms TimeField default value

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I making an edit form using [**WTForms**](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms).

Now I want to make a default value that prepopulated from database in the [TimeField](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/fields/html5.py#L71) form.

[image]

Here is the snippet of the code on the form above:

```
from wtforms.fields.html5 import TimeField

class ScheduleForm(Form):
    start_at = TimeField('Start at',validators=[required()])
    end_at = TimeField('End at', validators=[required()])
    # ...
    # ...
```

I try to call the **`obj`** argument on the route that I called the form like this:

```
@app.route('/edit_schedule/<int:schedule_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_schedule(schedule_id):
    schedule = Schedule.query.filter_by(id=schedule_id).first()

    print(schedule.start_at) # I got the value from database here
    print(schedule.end_at) # I got the value from database here

    form = ScheduleForm(obj=schedule) # call the obj argument
```

But the value on that field still didn't prepopulate, and then I try to make default value like this:

```
form = ScheduleForm(obj=schedule)
form.end_at.default = schedule.start_at
form.end_at.default = schedule.end_at
```

still didn't work, then I tried to add this line on the bellow the default value that I set above:

```
form.process()
```

Still didn't work, then I try to use `lambda`:

```
form.start_at.default = lambda: db.session.query(Schedule.start_at).filter_by(id=schedule.id).first()
form.end_at.default = lambda: db.session.query(Schedule.end_at).filter_by(id=schedule.id).first()
```

No one on all of the ways above works.

So the point of my question is, how to set or prepopulate the default value on the [TimeField](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/341f338d75f62453c403bf9c2b9503730a6712c7/src/wtforms/fields/html5.py#L71)..?

**EDIT**: here is the snippet of my model code:

```
class Schedule(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schedule'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_at = db.Column(db.Time())
    end_at = db.Column(db.Time())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this by set default value on my template, like the line below:

```
{{ f.render_field(form.start_at, value=schedule.start_at) }}
{{ f.render_field(form.end_at, value=schedule.end_at) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to populate `form.start_at.data` and `form.end_at.data`

```
form.end_at.data = schedule.start_at
form.end_at.data = schedule.end_at
```

I'm guessing that default value gets initialized once on the initialization.

Comment: Still don't work, but, very Thank you have replied to my question @DarkSuniuM